# Objective C Cordova callbacks with static void from instance method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm building a Cordova plugin that can perform DNS Queries. Since the operation is asynchronous  I need to use a callback to return the value.

I have

```
#import <dns_sd.h>

....

- (void)dnsQuery:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    id domain = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    DNSServiceRef serviceRef;

    DNSServiceQueryRecord(&serviceRef, 0, 0, "hmspl.de", kDNSServiceType_TXT,
                      kDNSServiceClass_IN, queryCallback, command);

    DNSServiceProcessResult(serviceRef);
    DNSServiceRefDeallocate(serviceRef);
}
```

Then the callback, which is a `static void`:

```
static void queryCallback(DNSServiceRef sdRef, DNSServiceFlags flags, uint32_t interfaceIndex,
                      DNSServiceErrorType errorCode, const char *fullname, uint16_t rrtype,
                      uint16_t rrclass, uint16_t rdlen, const void *rdata, uint32_t ttl, void *context) {

if (errorCode == kDNSServiceErr_NoError && rdlen > 1) {
    NSMutableData *txtData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:rdlen];

    for (uint16_t i = 1; i < rdlen; i += 256) {
        [txtData appendBytes:rdata + i length:MIN(rdlen - i, 255)];
    }

    NSString *theTXT = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:txtData.bytes length:txtData.length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",    

    //PROBLEM HERE
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:theTXT callbackId:context.callbackId]; 
   }
}

@end
```

I need to return a callback with the initial method:

```
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:theTXT callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

But I can't use `self` in the `static void` method.

How can I return the value `theTXT` to cordova and pass `command.callbackId` from the original method to the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter from `DNSServiceQueryRecord` is the application context, instead of passing the cordova's command, pass self as a parameter

In your .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * callbackId;
```

In your .m

```
- (void)dnsQuery:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    self.callbackId = command.callbackId;

    id domain = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    DNSServiceRef serviceRef;

    DNSServiceQueryRecord(&serviceRef, 0, 0, "hmspl.de", kDNSServiceType_TXT,
                          kDNSServiceClass_IN, queryCallback, (__bridge void*)self);

    DNSServiceProcessResult(serviceRef);
    DNSServiceRefDeallocate(serviceRef);
}
```

So you can use it now inside the queryCallback

```
static void queryCallback(DNSServiceRef sdRef, DNSServiceFlags flags, uint32_t interfaceIndex,
                      DNSServiceErrorType errorCode, const char *fullname, uint16_t rrtype,
                      uint16_t rrclass, uint16_t rdlen, const void *rdata, uint32_t ttl, void *context) {

if (errorCode == kDNSServiceErr_NoError && rdlen > 1) {
    NSMutableData *txtData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:rdlen];

    for (uint16_t i = 1; i < rdlen; i += 256) {
        [txtData appendBytes:rdata + i length:MIN(rdlen - i, 255)];
    }

    NSString *theTXT = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:txtData.bytes length:txtData.length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",    

    [context.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:theTXT callbackId:context.callbackId]; 
   }
}
```